# TypeError: weeklyData.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror

```js
import { useWheather } from "../../contexts/WheatherContex";

import FeatureForcastItem from "./FeatureForcastItem";

function FutureForecast() {
    const { weeklyData } = useWheather();

    console.log("WEEKLYDATA in COMPONENTS", weeklyData);

    return (
        <div id="future" className="wrapper">
            {weeklyData.map((day, i) => {
                return <FeatureForcastItem key={i} dayInfo={day} />;
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

export default FutureForecast;
```

[image]

Not work like this but if remove the weeklyData section it working and we can see the data weeklyData from console.log

```js
import { useWheather } from "../../contexts/WheatherContex";

// import FeatureForcastItem from "./FeatureForcastItem";

function FutureForecast() {
    const { weeklyData } = useWheather();

    console.log("WEEKLYDATA in COMPONENTS", weeklyData);

    return (
        <div id="future" className="wrapper">
            {/* {weeklyData.map((day, i) => {
                return <FeatureForcastItem key={i} dayInfo={day} />;
            })} */}
        </div>
    );
}

export default FutureForecast;
```

[image]

How can I pass this error and why its happing!

Comment: maybe try `weeklyData.length && weeklyData.map`, how does useWheather return its data. It's not doing an async task is it?

Comment: `weeklyData` is an object at one point which has no `map` method

Comment: How can I render the FeatureForcasatItem anyway @evolutionxbox

Comment: @Mohammed its worked thanks. But what is the issue over here? Why did that happen?

Comment: @HasanTezcan, that's great - I think what was happening is that somehow, your react component is trying to rum .map on something other than an array i.e. an object, just as evolutionxbox stated. With the code I provided, you're saying only run this when it is an array that has something inside it. You might have to dig back into your code to understand at what point your data is not an array and fix it.